# Barcode app for IOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am writing my first ever mobile app for IOS using Xamarin and i need to use the camera to scan a product barcode similar to the function of many shopping apps. Would any of you lovely people know how i go about this or if there are any plug-ins for this?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Did you try to research any yourself?  https://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile

Comment: And this one https://components.xamarin.com/view/scandit

Comment: iOS also has built-in barcode scanning

Comment: Thank you all. Apologies for the rudimentary question. I am totally new to mobile app development and wasn't aware of any resource boards. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, I have found ZXing Mobile to be the best option as far as reading barcodes is concerned.

The syntax is very .NET friendly:

```
buttonScan.Click += (sender, e) => {

var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scanner.Scan();

if (result != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
};
```

Source and more info: https://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile